# Scrptservice Webservice in MS VS 2005 and HTTP POST/CORS/Firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox, cross-site

I am trying to develop a Ajax Webservice using VS2005 and IIS6. Its purpose is to query a database and return records as text/csv (not my choice!) based on a filtered MS Access Table. The Service must be accessible from any Client Browser (provided it supports Ajax and XMLHTTPRequest object) with the most likely being a Linux Server. This obviously involves the phenomenon of Cross-site HTTP requests. When the client is MS IE 8, it works without any fuss, probably because of that Web Tool's slapdash implementation of security. The problem arises in Firefox 12, where calling a function of the service returns HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden. The web service code, in VB is as follows:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Web.Script.Services

Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.Odbc


<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://chpt.co.uk/CastusDataTransport")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> <ScriptService()> _
Public Class TransferToolData
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    Const AccConStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data       Source=c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Castus_Server\App_Data\db1.mdb"

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetJobRecords(ByVal ClientID As Long) As String

    LogGrabJobData("Request for Job Data")

    Return GrabJobData(ClientID)
End Function

Private Function GrabJobData(ByVal ID As Long) As String

    Dim strData As String
    Dim MyDB As New OleDbConnection
    Dim drGet As OleDbDataReader
    Dim cmdRetrieve As New OleDbCommand
    Dim cs As String
    Dim RecCount As Long

    cs = AccConStr
    MyDB = New OleDbConnection(cs)
    cmdRetrieve.Connection = MyDB
    cmdRetrieve.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Job_Data WHERE Client_ID = " & ID.ToString
    cmdRetrieve.Connection.Open()
    drGet = cmdRetrieve.ExecuteReader
strData = "’Job_ID’, ’Client_ID’, ’Status_ID’, ’Product_ID’, ’Serial_No’, ’Date_IN’, ’RA_Scale’, ’Location’, ’Manager’, ’Operator’, ’Stage’\n"

    RecCount = 0

    Do While (drGet.Read())
        strData &= Convert.ToString(drGet.Item("Job_ID")) & ","
        strData &= Convert.ToString(drGet.Item("Client_ID")) & ","
        strData &= Convert.ToString(drGet.Item("Status_ID")) & ","
        strData &= Convert.ToString(drGet.Item("Product_ID")) & ","
        'strData &= DelimitTextQuotes(Convert.ToString(drGet.Item("Client_Ref"))) & ","
        strData &= DelimitTextQuotes(Convert.ToString(drGet.Item("Serial_No"))) & ","
        strData &= Format(drGet.Item("Date_IN"), "d") & ","
        'strData &= DelimitTextQuotes(Convert.ToString(drGet.Item("Notes"))) & ","
        strData &= Convert.ToString(drGet.Item("RA_Scale")) & ","
        strData &= DelimitTextQuotes(Convert.ToString(drGet.Item("Location"))) & ","
        strData &= DelimitTextQuotes(Convert.ToString(drGet.Item("Manager"))) & ","
        strData &= DelimitTextQuotes(Convert.ToString(drGet.Item("Operator"))) & ","
        strData &= Convert.ToString(drGet.Item("Stage")) & "\n"

        RecCount += 1
    Loop

    Return strData
End Function
```

And the client side calls it in the most pedestrian way:

```
function makeCall(){        
    var xmlHttp;
try {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                alert("This sample only works in browsers with AJAX support"); 
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Create result handler 
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
            document.getElementById("result").value = xmlHttp.responseText;
        }
    }
         var url;
    url = "http://chpt.co.uk/Castus_Server/TransferToolData.asmx/GetJobRecords";
    var body = '{"ClientID":';
    body = body + document.getElementById("num1").value + '}';
    xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xmlHttp.send(body);
}
```

The 403 error seems to come on the Preflight request from the Client (which I note that IE simply skips – a *bad design fault* that I wish other browsers would lower themselves to right now). The IIS Web Application is configured to return the following HTTP Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Access-Control-Allow-Headers  Origin,cache-control,man,messagetype,x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods POST,OPTIONS
```

The Firefox Browser/Server send the following headers:

```
Request URL:
http://chpt.co.uk/Castus_Server/TransferToolData.asmx/GetJobRecords

Request Method:
OPTIONS

Status Code:
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden


Request Headers
15:05:03.984

  Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
  Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
  Accept-Language:en-gb,en;q=0.5
  Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
  Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
  Cache-Control:no-cache
  Connection:keep-alive
  Host:chpt.co.uk
  Origin:null
  Pragma:no-cache
  User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0


Response Headers
?1984ms

   Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin,cache-control,man,messagetype,x-requested-with
   Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
   Access-Control-Max-Age:120
   Content-Length:1827
   Content-Type:text/html
   Date:Thu, 17 May 2012 14:04:54 GMT
   MicrosoftOfficeWebServer:5.0_PubServer:Microsoft-IIS/6.0
   X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Now I have read the ‘Bible’ web page on this subject, [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control#Access-Control-Allow-Methods][1] and have learned a few things but not the solution to my present problem. Just wondered if anyone could see where I was going wrong or point me in the right direction. Hope I haven’t bored everyone and that I have provided enough detail on my predicament.

Answer (score 0):

As it is clear no one seems to know this one, and I can't waste any more time on it (I have already designed and proffered a workaround solution) I shall close this question down. It would seem that there is simply a glitch in the Cross-site HTTP Request API when using ScriptService() webservice. I shall try this again in a few months time to see if the problem has cleared up 'All by itself'! When I have a solution, I shall publish it here...
Jim McGoldrick
cablesafe.co.uk